# merging two rows with identical values and adding two specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner learning pandas, I have a dataframe like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvaj1.png)

I want the output as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq084.png)
I want to add Quantity and total quantity and retain the rest as it is.
I tried using the code:

```
d.groupby(['Sl.No','Catalogue No.','Catalogue Description','Nature of component','Compartment Width','Compartment Height', 'UOM']).sum().reset_index()
```

it yielded this output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8agdf.png)

Comment: So you want to leave `Sl.No` out of your groupby?

Comment: It is not clear what the desired output is and how it differs from the original dataframe.

Comment: I would like to retain the Sl.No and in the output what I am trying to do sum up quantity and total quantity while retaining the rest common features of both rows

Comment: df = d.groupby(['Catalogue No.','Catalogue Description','Nature of component','Compartment Width','Compartment Height', 'UOM']).sum().reset_index()
df['Sl.No'] = df.index
Try the above two lines of code. I have answered below.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the Sl.No from group by and try.

```
df = d.groupby(['Catalogue No.','Catalogue Description','Nature of component','Compartment Width','Compartment Height', 'UOM']).sum().reset_index()
```

if you want S.No as column

```
df['Sl.No'] = df.index
```

Comment: Thank you for your support the code is working as expected

Comment: Can you accept my answer and close the question.